# Describe a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ in $F=\{1_{E} \in \mathbb{R^R} | E \subset \mathbb{R} \text { finite } \}$ which converges to $1_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Tags: general-topology

Describe a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ in $F=\{1_{E} \in \mathbb{R^R} | E \subset \mathbb{R}  \text { finite } \}$ which converges to $1_{\mathbb{R}}$.

I defined $I = \{E \in \mathbb{R} | E \text{ finite } \}$ and $E_1 \leq E_2$ iff $E_1 \subset E_2$. I showed that this is a directed set by setting $E = E_1 \cup E_2$ then $E$ is finite since $E_1, E_2$ are, and $E_1 \subset E$ $E_2 \subset E$ thus, $E_1 \leq E$ and $E_2 \leq E$.

Then I defined a net $(I, \leq) \to F$ by $E \to 1_{E} =: x_E$. I wanna show for a neighbourhood. $U$ of $1_{\mathbb{R}}$ then there is a tail in $U$. Since $U$ is a nbh there is an open set $A$ s.t. $1_{\mathbb{R}} \in A \subset U.$ $A$ is open and $A = \prod_{r \in \mathbb{R}} A_r$ where $A_r \not = \mathbb{R}$ for finitely many $r \in \mathbb{R}.$ Thus for some $G \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $A_r$ open neighbourhood of $1 \in \mathbb R$ $\forall r \in G$ and $A_r = \mathbb R \ \forall r \in \mathbb R/ G$

But here it gets tricky for me and I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: What is the topology of R^R?  If it is the product topology, then let the directed set be R and define x_r to be Pi_(u < r) x Pi_(u >= r).

Comment: What is Pi_(u < r) x Pi_(u >= r) @WilliamElliot?

Comment: (Pi_(u < r) u) x (Pi_(u >= r)  u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your net indeed works. Let $U$ be a basic product open neighbourhood of $1_{\mathbb{R}}$. This means that we have that the set $U$ is determined by a finite set of open neighbourhoods of $1$, say $U_{r_1}, \ldots, U_{r_N}$, for finitely many points $r_1, \ldots r_N$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$U = \{f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}: \forall 1 \le i \le N: f(r_i) \in U_{r_i}\}$$
You could also write this set as $$\prod_{r \in \mathbb{R}} U_r$$ where all $U_r = \mathbb{R}$ if $r \notin \{x_{r_0},\ldots, x_{r_N}\}$ but it's the same set.

Now define $E_0 = \{x_{r_1}. \ldots x_{r_N}\} \in I$.

If $E \ge E_0$ or equivalently $E_0 \subseteq E$, then $1_E \in U$, as $1_E$ is $1$ on all points of $E_0$ specifically and those determine membership of $U$.
So the net converges to $1_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Had to read it carefully, but now I understand and want to thank you for a good answer! :)

Comment: @Olba12 Glad I could help. I like nets..